# can't find simple flutter image slideshow package

Tags: flutter, slideshow

I cannot find a Flutter slideshow or carousel package that allows me to animate images. The transition effect I want to use is a simple crossfade. I tried a lot of flutter packages without success. Thanks

Comment: did you try [carousel slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)?

Comment: Thanks but they don't allow crossfade transitions.